# MySQL - How to insert into multiple tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I'am new to MySQL, so please be nice :)

I would like to insert data from a php form into 3 different tables, which all have foreign keys. How can I write an insert command which updates all 3 tables at once, because if I try to update a table manually then I get an error because of the missing references.
Do I have to deal with "NULL" entries and update every table after another or is it possible to solve this with one single command? Like MySQLi_Multi_Query?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please post the relevant section of the schema?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're most likely going to have to insert things in order of their dependence.  So if you have three tables (A, B, and C) we'll assume C depends on B and B depends on A.  We'll also assume each table has primary keys AID, BID, and CID respectively.

1. You'd insert your row into A and get AID.
2. Then you'd insert your row into B using the AID you got from step 1.
3. Then you'd insert your row into C using the BID (and perhaps AID) you got from step 2 (and perhaps 1)

Comment: In your way, we have to execute sql one by one, this may cause perfmance problems. Is there a solution that can insert all these related rows in one sql? Now, I'm thinking, if I can get a list of AID without insert rows right now?

Comment: You could look into bulk inserts with MySQL (I only have experience with it in MSSQL).  Then you could wrap all three bulk inserts into a transaction (so if one fails, all are rolled back)

Answer (score 32):

You can do it in 3 Methods:

First & Recommended. USING SELECT IN THE INSERT VALUE:

> ```
>    INSERT INTO user (name)
>      VALUES ('John Smith');
> INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height)
>      VALUES ((SELECT id FROM user WHERE name='John Smith'), 83, 185);
> ```

Second. USING LAST_INSERT_ID IN THE INSERT VALUE:

```
INSERT INTO a (id)
     VALUES ('anything');
INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height)
     VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),83, 185);
```

Third. USING PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php
// Connecting to database
$link = mysql_connect($wgScriptsDBServerIP, $wgScriptsDBServerUsername, $wgScriptsDBServerPassword, true);
if(!$link || !@mysql_SELECT_db($wgScriptsDBName, $link)) {
echo("Cant connect to server");
    exit;
}

// Values to insert
$name = 'John Smith';
$weight = 83;
$height = 185;

// insertion to user table
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('$name')";
$result = mysql_query( $sql,$conn );
// retrieve last id
$user_id = mysql_insert_id( $conn );
mysql_free_result( $result );

// insertion to user_details table
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height) VALUES ($user_id, $weight, $height)";
$result = mysql_query( $sql,$conn );
mysql_free_result( $result );
?>
```

Comment: Careful with the first and recommended suggestion. That assumes there is only one "John Smith". If name is not a UNIQUE column, that is asking for trouble. Using LAST_INSERT_ID() is the way to go.

Comment: Are these multi-table inserts atomic? i.e. Either 2 tables are updated or zero (if there was any intermediate errors)? Or does one have to use `begin transaction` to ensure atomicity?

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in your syntax for the method 1.

```
INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height)
     VALUES (SELECT(id FROM user WHERE name='John Smith'), 83, 185);
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height)
     VALUES ((SELECT id FROM user WHERE name='John Smith'), 83, 185);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) 
The sense of foreign_key is to associate a value in a field with a pre_existing value somewhere else. So you should make your inserts in a logic order.

2)
 If you want to avoid logical restrictions you should

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0  // disable key checks in server
INSERT ... // any order
INSERT ...
...
SET foreign_key_checks = 1
```